# How to compare two strings [已 ] , [巳 ] and see how close to each others? Using PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried many different ways to do this task:

1. Levenshtein
2. Fuzzy
3. Damerau Levenshtein
4. Jaro Winkler
5. Smith Waterman Gotoh

**My code:**

```
<?php
        echo levenshtein("ЛИЧНА КАРТАlоемптY CARO Пренные ЂУРЂЕВИЋ Hercinian","Михајло Ђурђевић")."<br>";
?>
```

Output:

[image]

All of this is working properly with the English language. however, In my case, I have many different languages[Arabic, Chinese, Russian...etc]. Some letters in these languages are similar to each other.

Example:

- in Arabic "ت" & "ث"
- in Chinese "已" & "巳"
- in Russian "ћ" & "h"

How to deal with these letters multibyte language to get good accuracy?

Comment: I don't know enough about those specific languages to say if you should do this in all cases, but if you can determine that two letters are *basically interchangable* in a certain language, then you could just replace all of the more rare letter with the more common letter before calculating the similarity -- or you could calculate similarity both with and without the more rare letter. I don't know if there's a one-size-fits-all answer here though.

Comment: @TKoL Thank you very much. I got it. However, I hope to get a better solution for this which can work for any language. Maybe there is a way to make this using (AI or ML) or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only have 2 suggestions.

1. Convert the character to it's codepoint value using [IntlChar::ord](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intlchar.ord.php).

Most of the time the time the codepoint value [should also be close to the other character](https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer#e=2KvYquW3suW3s9GbaA). (use Levenshtein on this instead).

This would work for your first 2 examples.

---

2. Convert the character to an image with [imagestring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php)
   Use [pHash](https://www.phash.org/) on the images to see the difference in image.

[PHP implementation](https://github.com/xwiz/phash)

This would work for all 3 of your examples