# Wrong levenshtein UTF8

Tags: php, levenshtein-distance

From here [Levenshtein distance on diacritic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271656/levenshtein-distance-on-diacritic-characters)
I'm using this PHP function to calculate the levenshtein distance for UTF8 characters.

```
function levenshtein_php($str1, $str2){
  $length1 = mb_strlen( $str1, 'UTF-8');
  $length2 = mb_strlen( $str2, 'UTF-8');
  if( $length1 < $length2) return levenshtein_php($str2, $str1);
  if( $length1 == 0 ) return $length2;
  if( $str1 === $str2) return 0;
  $prevRow = range( 0, $length2);
  $currentRow = array();
  for ( $i = 0; $i < $length1; $i++ ) {
    $currentRow=array();
    $currentRow[0] = $i + 1;
    $c1 = mb_substr( $str1, $i, 1, 'UTF-8') ;
    for ( $j = 0; $j < $length2; $j++ ) {
      $c2 = mb_substr( $str2, $j, 1, 'UTF-8' );
      $insertions = $prevRow[$j+1] + 1;
      $deletions = $currentRow[$j] + 1;
      $substitutions = $prevRow[$j] + (($c1 != $c2)?1:0);
      $currentRow[] = min($insertions, $deletions, $substitutions);
    }
    $prevRow = $currentRow;
  }
  return $prevRow[$length2];
}
```

When I'm using it with
$string1 = 'încat de counștițe';
$string2= 'încântat';

I get that the levensthein difference is 13 , which I consider to be wrong.

The only 2 options that I see are the following changes to $string1:

```
    1)
    a) add the characters 'ânt' to reach $string1 = 'încântat de counștițe';
    b) delete the characters ' de counștițe' to reach $string1 = 'încântat' ;

which would lead to a difference of 17 changes


    2) 
    a) replace 'a' with 'â' to reach $string1 = 'încât de counștițe';
    b) delete 't de cou' to reach $string1 = 'încânștițe';
    c) delete 'ș' to reach $string1 = 'încântițe';
    d) add characters 'at' to reach to reach $string1 = 'încântatițe';
    e) remove characters 'ițe' to reach $string1 = 'încântat';

with an levensthein distance of 15
```

Could you please help me correct the above levensthein_php code to return the correct difference. If there is any other existing PHP function I'd be happy to use it, however I unerstood that there is no  function mb_levenshtein.

If it matters I'm running it on PHP 7.4.33.

Comment: Do you need an accented letter to match the corresponding non-accented letter?  Or should they be treated as different?

Comment: Related: [How to compare two strings `已`, `巳` and see how close to each others? Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62873237/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example of calculating the distance contains an error in my opinion:

```
a) replace 'a' with 'â' to reach $string1 = 'încât de counștițe';
b) delete 't de cou' to reach $string1 = 'încânștițe';
c) delete 'ș' to reach $string1 = 'încântițe';
d) add characters 'at' to reach $string1 = 'încântatițe';
e) remove characters 'ițe' to reach $string1 = 'încântat';
```

The last two lines should read:

```
d) replace characters 'iț' with 'at' to reach $string1 = 'încântate';
e) remove character 'e' to reach $string1 = 'încântat';
```

Therefore the result is 13 and not 15, and the function works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your example text implies that the character set is limited to certain Western European alphabets.  I suggest you use the suitable conversion routine to change from UTF-8 to Latin1 (or other suitable encoding).  Then the characters would be single-byte, and no "mb" routines are needed.

Try MySQL's CHARACTER SET cp1250 and latin2 -- they seem to have the desired s or t with cedilla.  Try the _general_ci and _croatian_ci COLLATIONs if you need case and accent folding.  Or _bin to be case and accent sensitive.

Comment: do you mean character sets: ISO-8859-1 (Western Europe)? then it won't work as I need also characters such as ș ț   or at least I can't find these characters here: https://www.charset.org/charsets/iso-8859-1

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see a 1-byte "latin" charset that handles Romanian, or at least not one that MySQL implements.

Comment: @MMT [ISO-8859-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-16) or [windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250).

Comment: And I don't think either of those is supported by any single-byte character set in MySQL.

Comment: Checking further...  cp1250 and latin2 may have what you need for Romanian.

Comment: @Olivier would this work to find the levensthein distance of Romanian characters? My understanding that the php levensthein function works only with just 1 byte characters. I do not have any problems with mysql, my question is about php. Would you have a code example?